# How to use unique in laravel queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I don't want a user to ask the same question twice.

If user 'John' has a question 'Whats the time?', he shouldn't be able to post it again, although a different user can post the same question!

This is my laravel rule code for validation the 'question' text field:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'question'=>'required|unique:questions,question,2,people_id'
    ];
}
```

But this is allowing the user with id '2' to post the question, how do I fix it.
Also, how can I replace '2' with `Auth::id()`, it shows error `undefined class constant id`.

Table structure

```
questions-> table name
question-> column name
people_id-> where Auth Id is stored, like '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with this query

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'question'=>'required|unique:questions,question,!'.Auth::id().',people_id'
    ];
}
```